# Utility to search the content of external hard disk (if possible index it in advance)?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching through txt, pdf and doc files](https://superuser.com/questions/25092/searching-through-txt-pdf-and-doc-files)

How to search my contents in my portable hard disk quickly (just like a google desktop)? having lots of materials in the harddisk, searching becomes harder. Is there a way that i can index my entire hard disk (for txt / pdf / html ) files and just search the content like a google desktop ?

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching through txt, pdf and doc files](http://superuser.com/questions/25092/searching-through-txt-pdf-and-doc-files) and [File search apps?](http://superuser.com/questions/165640/file-search-apps)

Comment: Check out [File Content Finder](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/file-content-finder/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It's specifically designed for searching file contents without indexing. It supports all major file formats - pdf, doc(x), xls(x), pptx, rtf, and others.
Its filtering lets you optimise and refine your search by multiple criteria - file type, creation/modification dates, etc.

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/data-transformer/id1490843070) or the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/data-transformer/9p2xp6nt2pv2).

Answer (score 0):

Windows indexing service doesn't allow indexing of external devices. Google Desktop however can by [selecting so in preferences](http://desktop.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=17227). Suggest disabling Windows indexing and using Google Desktop instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using windows then [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) is a must , its much faster than the likes of google desktop etc and you can choose which devices to index. Give it a go you will never look back