# How to find all files with a specific extension in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, search, file-search

On a computer with Windows 8, how can I find all files with a specific extension within a drive or network location?

For example, how can I find all *.docx files on my hard drive?

Comment: Sorry for my wrong answer that I posted earlier. Network location is a totally different story. Cannot really help there. Locally just use the search box in the Explorer Window.

Comment: Here's a similar question but not restricted to Win 8: http://superuser.com/questions/25092/searching-through-txt-pdf-and-doc-files

Comment: @AthomSfere, I've used the built-in tools in the Windows Explorer and the Windows 8 Metro interface.  It just seems odd that the built-in search functionality in a major Windows release could be so pathetic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Powershell command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ *.docx -Recurse
```