# Finding files on the hard disk containing specific text– Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-word, search

I know that I created a file using Word and saved it at some time in the past. Now I need that file and I have no idea what I call it, but I do know that I use a specific and unique phrase in it. I'm sure that Windows probably includes such a utility?

Where is it, and how do I best use it?

Thanks.

Ross

Comment: Windows Search built into Windows since, well forever, has this capability.  Just setup the search to look into the contents of the file pretty much the same way, exactly, how you have done it since well forever.

Comment: You can also just look for `*.*.docx` then sort by date.

Comment: Or *.*.doc if it is an older word document.

Comment: I have found that the search in the Windows Explorer is very very slow, however…

Comment: Here's some other SuperUser threads that tackle this: http://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-on-windows-7 and http://superuser.com/questions/25092/searching-through-txt-pdf-and-doc-files

Answer (score 0):

Simply open Windows Explorer and click into the search box. You should see the "Search Tools" appear in the top bar. Click on "Advanced options" and you will see some selections for "In non-indexed locations", make sure that "File Contents" is selected. Note that this will slow down your searches - probably rather a lot! But this ensures that the contents will be searched even if your file is hidden away in a location that Windows Search does not index.

You could also make sure that Windows Search Index is indexing all possible locations.

Be warned though that I've never found Windows Search all that reliable.

UPDATE: If you are not finding Windows Search all that reliable, you could try a GREP tool for Windows. Please note that I've not tried any of these (I use SharePoint for document management).

- [dnGrep](http://dngrep.github.io/) seems the most likely candidate. It has a plugin to read Word 2007+ files
- [Funduc have a free macro](http://www.funduc.com/word_sr.htm) for Word that might do what you want. They also have more powerful but non-free tools.
- The free [Windows GREP](http://www.wingrep.com/features.htm) tool will search in binary files but I don't know whether it will pick up text in docx files.
- The shareware [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com/msword.html) will search in both .doc and .docx files but it is incredibly expensive! EUR119 for a single license! There is a free trial though.
- [Common Resource Grep](https://bitbucket.org/cryanfuse/crgrep) is free but is Linux only.

Comment: yes, that has been my problem: it's a nice novelty but I've never found it the 100% accurate. Anybody know of any freebie third-party apps that are 100% accurate?